# Is there "oldline" character in Java?

Tags: java, terminal, newline

Is there exist the opposite to the newline `'\n'` character in Java which will move back to the previous line in the console?

Comment: @SLaks he probably meant previous line :P

Comment: " Is there exist the opposite to the newline '\n' character in Java?" In which other programming language have you actually seen something that's opposite of `\n`?

Comment: @BheshGurung - They aren't programming languages, but many character sets (ASCII, Unicode, ISO 8859-*, etc.) have a "REVERSE LINE FEED" character.

Comment: I think this is an appropriate question - but asked in a really funny manner. Answers should likely include various "terminal" information. I suspect there are some good duplicates.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

ASCII doesn't standardize a "line starve" or reverse line feed control character. Some character based terminals/terminal emulators recognize control code sequences that move the cursor up a line; these aren't Java-specific, and depend on your OS and configuration. Here's a starting point if you're using Linux: http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man4/console_codes.4.html

Comment: Let's also not forget the Unicode character "REVERSE LINE FEED" (U+008D). Like the ANSI terminal escape sequences, it's not supported everywhere, but it's definitely supported in some places (e.g., paper printers).

Answer (score 5):

Java supports Unicode, which has the character ["REVERSE LINE FEED" (U+008D)](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/8d/index.htm). In Java it would be `'\u008D'` (as a `char`) or `"\u008D"` (as a `String`). Whether this would do what you want on a console, printout, or whatever, depends on the device. Java does not define any behavior for that character.